# jQuery 1.7 selector error

Tags: jquery, ajax

this is my very first question.

I'm working on a fully Ajax system with jQuery, and it works fine with 1.6.2. When I tried to upgrade it to 1.7, this piece of code stopped working properly:

```
$("a[class!='']").live("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

In 1.6.2, it prevents all hyperlink tags from working as a link if they have a class, but in 1.7 it stopped ALL links from working as real links, even those without classes.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hBehg/

Comment: Have you tried `$('a[class])`? Checking for an empty value might not work well if the element does not even have the `class` attribute. *Edit:* This seems to work.

Comment: Indeed I can repro this.  I added a fiddle to the question.  If you toggle between 1.7 and 1.6.4 you get the exact behavior described by the OP

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `$('a[class]')`, this will select all elements which have the class attribute. <del>As I said in my comment, checking for an empty value might not work if the element does not even have a `class` attribute.</del>

**Update:** As pointed out by [@Sidnicious](https://stackoverflow.com/users/84745/sidnicious), the documentation describes that this selector will also select those elements which do not have that attribute. If it didn't in 1.6, then it actually must have been a bug in that version, or they changed the description without mentioning it.

Of course, if you indeed have an empty `class` attribute, i.e. `<a class="">`, this will not work.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hBehg/2/)

**Update 2:** As [@lonesomeday](https://stackoverflow.com/users/417562/lonesomeday) mentions in his comment, `$('a[class][class!=""]')` does work as you intended with `$(a[class!=""])`.

As others said, you can change to `on` in jQuery 1.7, which unifies the event handling methods, but it won't solve your particular problem.

Comment: +1, This certainly seems like the best approach.  However it still seems unclear if the behavior reported by the OP is a bug in jQuery or not (and if so which version is *wrong*).

Comment: See my answer. As far as I can tell, the [name!=value] selector is documented to work like this (even though it’s a little bit confusing).

Answer (score 3):

The jQuery docs [describe the [name!=value] selector like this](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/):

> Select elements that either don't have the specified attribute, or do have the specified attribute but not with a certain value.

In your case, it will select every `a` which doesn’t have a `class` or whose class is not equal to an empty string. `<a></a>` and `<a class=""></a>` are not the same.

That might actually have been a bug in jQuery 1.6!

Comment: In fact, I wanted it  to select only elements with at least 1 class, classes with empty strings not included.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.filter` to get the desired result in jQuery 1.7:

```
$('a').filter('[class]').on("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/hBehg/1/

If you replace `.on` with `.live` it no longer works right:

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/hBehg/4/

Although `.bind` works fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/hBehg/5/

Comment: @FelixKling I'd forgotten that, thanks for reminding me. Seems you can't use `.on` as a replacement for `.live` in those cases, either.

Comment: Good job, +1 to this answer as well

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
$("a").live("click",function(e){
    if ($(this).attr('class') === undefined) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

I've verified this works on 1.7 and 1.6.4.  It's less ideal than a selector which includes the predicate but it will get the job done.

Comment: Works, but as you said, not as elegant as a selector.